# How to force Vuejs to run watch functions

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue and have several watch functions like:

```
  ,watch:{
    'form.screw.thread':function(val, oldval){
      var box = this.$refs.screw_thread_radios;
      this.form.screw.thread_t = box.querySelector('input[value="' + val + '"] + label .name').innerHTML;
      this.form.screw.thread_image = UrlUtilities.get_file_in_url(box.querySelector('input[value="' + val + '"] + label img').getAttribute('src'));
    }

   [etc..]
```

My problem is that all those props will evaluate only on change (after changing) or, in other words, after interacting with the view/ui.
Instead, I need al of them to evaluate one time also on init. Is there a wa? Can't find useful infos on docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, the answer is: you cannot do it reliably. Or, to be more precise, even by passing `immediate: true`, in your function scope you won't have access to the same properties you could from a lifecycle hook like `'mounted'` (see comments above, for example `$refs`).

So I personally ended up abstracting the logic I needed into another function, defining it into the Vue's `methods` property. I then call that function both in `mounted` (for my init needs) and in watchers (instead of the original code) as needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass in the `immediate` property:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options

Example:

```
watch: {
  foo: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(nv, ov) { ... }
  }
}
```

Also another option would be to abstract the logic into a method and run it on a lifecycle hook. This would be useful if you also need to run the logic somewhere else.

Comment: I already investigated the immediate:true option, but there's a huge problem > I think it runs too early. For example, the $refs object at that point is empty.

Comment: so how to circumvent that problem?

Comment: Is there a way to call the watch functions onnexttip, for example?

Comment: If you rely on the ref to be there you will need to call the function once from a mounted lifecycle hook. In a data driven framework like Vue you shouldn’t rely on DOM nodes to begin with, but that is another point of concern.

Comment: yes that's another concern, but for nowI have to do like this. I need to write down form fields values, translated for a resume. But the real value (the one I'm going to send) is not to be translated, so I need to pick the label instead for the resume, via js (and I need it to be populated on init, thus the watched functions must be executed 1 time without waiting for user interaction).
Anyway, back to the issue #1, I can't find a way to call watched functions from mounted hook..

Comment: Offtopic: I see you use Vue+Laravel, interesting, because I'm thinking of learning Laravel too :)

Comment: There is no need to explicitly call a`watch` function. Just move the logic from your `watch` functions to separate functions. The watchers will call these functions, but on init within your `mounted` hook you can also call these functions.